# How do you structure resources in multi-module WPF applications?

Tags: wpf, xaml, architecture

I have a growing WPF solution where I have multiple projects within.

[image]

I have one main "module-selection" project that acts as the entry point when launching the application. From this one I typically load one or more of the "module" projects.

I have several "module"-projects that are quite big and are currently set up as class libraries.
At the bottom I have a common resource project where I keep and maintain all resources that are common for all the modules (typically themes, colors, control styles)

When everything is in one project you can define your global resources in the app.xaml. When you have resources in class libraries I believe this works as well run-time, but not design-time. The workaround is linking in the resources from every control or page that needs it. This latter solution works, but will then spend time loading the resources everywhere you define it and this impacts performance significantly.

What is the best practice to achieve dividing your LOB application into multiple projects while maintaining global resources in an proper fashion?